# How to add a style attribute to an element if it doesn't exist or just add the given styles to the pre-existing style attribute using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a script such that it adds an attribute style to an element with the given styles if it doesn't exist or just simply add the given styles to the pre-existing style attribute. Here is a piece of the code I wrote :

```
var style = function(sel, styl) { 
    var rVselect = document.querySelector(sel); 
    rVselect.getAttributeNode("style").value += styl; 
};
```

This works perfect but has a problem. This only works when there is a style attribute ( doesn't matter empty or have some content ) given to the element. I want it make a style attribute in absense of it and then insert the styles and in work as it is working now in presense of the style attribute i.e. just simply add the new styles to the pre-existing style attribute.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple. Here is a piece of code :

```
 var style = function(sel, styl) {
    var rVselect = document.querySelector(sel);
    rVselect.style += styl;
 };
```

If you want to add this to all matching elements go for this :

```
 var style = function(sel, styl) {
    var rVselect = document.querySelectorAll(sel);
    for( var i = 0; i < rVselect.length; ++i ) {
      rVselect[i].style += styl;
    };
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function(sel, styl) { 
  var rVselect = document.querySelector(sel); 
  rVselect.style = rVselect.style + styl; 
};
```

It takes existed styles and add styles passed to argument